# Extend Remote second monitor

Tags: ubuntu, display, multi-monitor

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I would like to extend my monitor by using another laptop.
I tried to use TeamViewer, but I didn't find an option to share part of monitor. 
Maybe someone knows of a program which can do this?